# How to setup :fail: default email address in cPanel?

Tags: email, exim, blackhole

How to setup a :fail: default email address in cPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load up CPanel
Go to "Set Default Address"

I think the options you require are in there. If not, can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

This feature is sometimes disabled by your hosting provider, so you may need to request it be enabled.

Comment: When I enter ":fail:" for the "forward to email address" inside of "Set Default Address" cPanel page... I am told "Forward address must be an email address or your account name." :/

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dumb, why do you need to enter :fail:? Can you explain what you're trying to achieve - i.e., what do you want to happen to the e-mail?

Comment: Ok. I have cronjobs setup in cPanel. Cronjobs MUST notify an email address for some reason. So I want them to notify :fail: - what do I need to know a cronjob has run every few minutes for??

Comment: I've just looked on CPanel and you can add the following to the end of the Cron Job to stop it from sending an e-mail: ">/dev/null 2>&1"

Comment: Alternatively, you can create a Forwarder by choosing "Forwarders" on the main CPanel page. Click "Add Forwarder", make up an e-mail address such as "cronjobs@yourdomain.com". Choose "Advanced" and select "Discard (Not Recommended)". This will just blackhole any e-mails to that address with no errors.